# Epson printer as a removable device in the notification area?

Tags: windows, usb, printer

I installed an Epson L3150 printer on Windows 10 (19041.546), but it is strange that the printer remains as a removable USB device. Just like a removable device in the notification area. Do not appear in windows explorer. Even uninstalling completely and reinstalling. It appears again as a removable USB. If I click remove, the printer will stop working. And just restarting the system to function normally.

Comment: Guess: the "removeable USB drive" contains drivers, configuration files etc., and Epson exposed several interfaces via USB, one of which is this simulated "drive".

Comment: The same thing happens with USB GSM adaptors. They not only contain the mobile-phone SIM hardware, but also the drivers that are used on the PC.

Comment: Ok, but is there any way to hide it?

Answer (score 2):

I think @dirkt is correct in the comments. The printer is most likely acting as multiple USB devices connected to a USB hub. One of these devices is the actual printer and the other one is a generic flash drive which provides driver files for ease of installation.

If you want to get rid of the built-in flash drive, remove its drive letter.

1. Right-click the *Start* button and select *Disk Management*.
2. Right-click the printer's USB drive and choose *Change drive letters and paths*.
3. Remove the drive letter and click OK.

Comment: There is no way to remove the drive letter in disk management. The printer is not showing up in windows explorer, just on the taskbar.

Comment: @bryanswy Do you mean it's showing as a removable device in notification area?

Comment: Yes. Exactly in the notification area. I'm trying to find a way to hide it.

Comment: @bryanswy Please [edit] your question and add that information. It's essential.

Answer (score 0):

if you eject it from the safely remove icon, it will tell you that the "usb composite device" is safe to remove. open the device manager, look under usb devices for the usb composite device now with an exclamation by it. if you click on it and go to properties it will say something about it being prepared for safe removal and it cant be managed. DISABLE IT HERE. chances are you have a wifi printer and no longer need the usb connection active to print after its setup. this seems to be a usb device built into the printer for newer versions of windows to easily grab the driver off of during install.